# What to do when underperforming in project

Tags: training, performance, projects

I have joined a IT company in last November 2020. I didn't get any training from the company but other joinees had training. I am basically from an electronics and telecommunication background. So I do have very little experience in coding.

But still when I got the interview for a development project, I was able to solve the coding questions in python and hence they took me in the project. Its been a month working on golang and api creation as a backend engineer. The tickets (tasks) assigned were in last week and I am unable to understand them. The basic part is I am able to understand but while debugging, and changing code in the codebase I am totally failing so what should I do?

I do know that once I get enough training I can do it I have discussed it with my manager as well. He said its normal and not to worry about it, and try to work on them. Can anyone share their thoughts on this?

Comment: You've discussed this with your manager, and he is happy with your current work output? If true, then you just keep going how you're going. it is not usual to feel a bit lost at a new job, so do not worry.

Comment: @Gregory Currie yes I have discussed it with my manager he said as a fresher in industry its totally normal to feel like that but what I am actually having problem is that morally I am feeling like maybe if I am unable to improve then I would become a dead-weight to the project and also I am trying my best in improving but still I am needing more time than the time allotted to me to work on those issues. So its sort of like making me feel if I made right decision to work in coding Industry or not thanks for the suggestions though 

Comment: @user124674 You might want to search for "imposter syndrome". That's a pretty common feeling, especially among those just entering the industry.

Comment: Ask for help and learn on your own in the meantime.

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing is transparency. Don't hide the fact that you are struggling. Inform your direct manager immediately if you hit a roadblock. Don't tell them "I can't do this, pls help!!", but "I've tried x, y, z without success. I think I need a, b and c to finish the task".

If you want training, don't wait for others to notice that you are untrained. Ask actively for it. I'm not too keen on unpaid overtime myself, so I try to do all my research and learning on company time. If you are able to pull this through is largely dependent on your company culture, so ask your colleagues.

On a positive Note: It seems you have told your manager and he is not concerned, so relax. Still, keep pressing for the things you need to succeed!

Answer (score 1):

My advice is don't get too hard on yourself. Your obviously doing a good job and have a good attitude if your manager says don't worry.

You mention you will be better able to do your job when you get training. I presume you mean training in coding? My advice here is don't wait for others to begin training you. If you are serious about having a career in software, start training yourself outside of work hours. Use the weekends and evenings to create small projects and put them on your Github, so you can access them when you need. Start small & educate yourself slowly.

Starting a new job in software is hard enough when you are experienced. It can be very daunting when you have little experience. When negative thoughts enter your mind and you think you can't do your job, instead look for solutions and think how you can become a better coder using the cast amount of resources available on the Internet. This will build up your confidence.

Well done on reaching out to the community here. That was a great first step.

Comment: There is a lot of pressure for people that do jobs that require a lot of learning to do so outside of work hours. However it's very much part of your job. What you're suggesting is working unpaid overtime. Of course there's nothing wrong with coding for fun on your own terms. But specifically to do your job? that's setting unrealistic standards for the future. I'd avoid this and try to learn on the job, that way they can also guide and prioritize what you learn. OP Mentioned their manager is fine with the situation and not to be to hard on themselves. It's probably best to heed that advice.

Comment: I agree to a point on this, especially unpaid overtime. However I've never had a software role where I didn't have to do research outside of normal hours. For me it's all part of being a software engineer. Constant learning and development.

Comment: @BobMeijer Being pragmatic, there is usually an enormous difference in career progression between people who do stuff out of work and people who do not. You will hardly ever find people at the upper tiers of a profession who are content with just working their eight hours and forgetting about anything work-related. While I agree with it being overtime, it may not be as unpaid as you believe, as it may allow you into top paying jobs that otherwise you would not be getting. It is fine to don't do that, but there is a price to be paid.